# Installing Magento Community Edition (free version) as two web sites in Apache

Tags: magento-1.7, database, magento-community, server-setup

I need to install Magento Community Edition (free version) as two web-sites in my web server (Apache 2.2), one MagentoCE with the sample data and one Magento CE without sample data. How to achieve this ? I have tried keeping one web-site with sample data (sample data given in the web site), but I am unable to proceed with installing a second web-site (with an empty database) because the installation gets halted in the process of installing.

Appreciate your comments!

Comment: Are you trying to create two separate instances of Magento or one instance and two websites in the instance?

Comment: I agree with brent, more information is needed. Are you trying to have 2 magento CE on two domains, or one magento over 2 domains with content on a different domain. What are you trying to achieve, we could help :)

Comment: I want to create two separate instances (i.e. two installation folders) of Magento CE (inside Apache 2.2). One with sample data, and the other without sample data.

Comment: Do you want to have two domains i.e. store1.domain.com and store2.domain.com or do you want to do domain.com/store1 and domain.com/store2 ?

Comment: @brentwpeterson: I want to have store1.domain.com and store2.domain.com. Important thing is store1.domain.com has the sample data, while store2.domain.com does not have sample data.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) What is the problem? Did you check the Debugging Tutorial? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up two separate virtual hosts for each domain (ie store1.domain.com and store2.domain.com).  Each virtual host will point to it's own, different, Magento directory (ie copy the directory from one to the other).

You will also need two different databases, one for each site.